# Retrieve xml-data from text-column

Tags: sql, xml, coldfusion

I've a table which has a field (datatype "text") that contains a xml-file. After some try and error I found out that the only way to fetch the complete xml-file from that table is to use the "FOR XML" clause of ms sql. 
But my next problem is, that the colum containing the xml-file is named something like "XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11D1-B105-00805F49916B" which is an invald identifier for cf.

Is there a way to access that column by its id instead of its name or what's the best way to access this column?

Edit:
The SQL statement I'm using is:

```sql
SELECT XmlPackage
FROM LogK3OnChange 
WHERE DealerID = IsNull(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.dealerid#">, DealerID)
AND LogID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.logid#">
FOR XML RAW
```

Regards,

Heiko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it

```
<cfoutput>#myQuery["XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11D1-B105-00805F49916B"][1]#</cfoutput>
```

does the trick

Answer (score 2):

If you embed your query in a sub-query you can give your column a name.

```
select
  (
    select *
    from YourTable
    for xml path('Row'), root('Root')
  ) as NewColumnName
```

With your query:

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT XmlPackage
    FROM LogK3OnChange 
    WHERE DealerID = IsNull(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.dealerid#">, DealerID)
          AND LogID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.logid#">
    FOR XML PATH
  ) AS NewColumnName
```

**Update:**
If you want the column to be a XML data type you should add the `type` keyword to your query. Not sure if that would make a difference for coldfusion.

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT XmlPackage
    FROM LogK3OnChange 
    WHERE DealerID = IsNull(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.dealerid#">, DealerID)
          AND LogID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.logid#">
    FOR XML PATH, TYPE
  ) AS NewColumnName
```

Comment: Sorry, seems to not work properly because I get an incomplete xml-file on that way.

Comment: Is it missing a root element?

Comment: No, it's just cut off somewhere before the real end of file

Comment: I know nothing about coldfusion and a bit a about SQL Server. Do you have anything in coldfusion that would limit the column size? A field definition or perhaps coldfusion uses the maximum varchar size 8000 (4000 for nvarchar). When using ADO to read this it has to be treated as nvarchar(max) type of field `ftMemo`. How much data do you get out?

Comment: Nearly 23160 characters or 24kb if I copy the output into a txt-file

Comment: I have no idea why that would happen. I doubt there is anything you can do on the SQL Server side.

Comment: Maybe @Ostfriese can try XML RAW, TYPE instead of XML PATH, TYPE or better XML AUTO, TYPE ? Cannot see any other options... in that case I don't think adding ELEMENTS would help.

Comment: Check your settings in the CF Admin - make sure that CLOB is checked (enable long text retrieval) and set your buffer sufficiently high to accomodate your content. This applies IF the data is stored in a TEXT field. If it's a character field then your issue may be that the data is too long for the field and there for truncated when it was inserted or updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better answer as it does not rely on a string that may potentially change in some later revision of coldfusion.

```
<cfoutput>#QueryName[QueryName.ColumnList][1]#</cfoutput>
```