# Sybase 15.5 ODBC driver cannot retrieve the full content in a text column if the data in it exceeds 32768 characters (2^15)

Tags: odbc, sap-ase

I store XML content as a string in a `text` column, but after upgrading to Sybase driver 15.5, I cannot retrieve the full string. It is always truncated to 32768 characters.

I have tried the `FOR XML AUTO, TYPE` keywords as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023730/retrieve-xml-data-from-text-column) but it did not work for me.

The driver I'm using is:

> Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.05.00.1

The server version is:

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 17163 ESD#3/P/Linux Intel/Linux 2.6.9-42.ELsmp i686/ase1503/2726/32-bit/FBO/Fri Feb  5 04:45:36 2010'

Does anyone know if it is a driver bug? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is about setting the textsize before running the query

```
set TEXTSIZE  2147483647
```

2147483647 is 2^ 31 - 1